# Fail Onclick Button GetText

Tags: android, onclick

Hi i developing an app for my homework,the app is about a android client to connect java server.The error message is this:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference*

In this method:

```
buttonconect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ip=ipAdress.getText().toString();
                Client.SERVERIP=ip;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Display.this, Connect.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

I try to call this string and save my Editext:This is my class Connect

```
private String serverMessage;
    public static String SERVERIP;----> here the error previous class
    // address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 2222;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
```

Whats wrong with this.Thx for all and sorry for my english

Comment: When you post to SO, and there is an error in the logs, always include the full stack trace of the log.  Also, always post the code that it references.  I don't see where you're using an EditText here.

Comment: The editext have the instance

Comment: I understand, but you haven't *shown* us the code with the EditText.  Where is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Connect activity should be registered in ActivityManifest.xml
2) Try to include the correct xml in Connect.java

Comment: if ipAdress is already defined in the MainActivity as a variable, i don't see how this will solve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

check your findViewbyId code and see if you are using the correct id for your edittext

Comment: are you sure? maybe try to add a log message after you assign the ipAdress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ipAdressEditText);
Log.i("LOG",""+ipAdress); 
to check if the edittext ipAdress is not null